# android: fade in animation

Tags: java, android

I try to fade in a buttons in a specific order. Each time one button fades, but the buttons fade in all together after the code is finished. I tried to use Thread.sleep after each fade order but it doesn't help at all. Does someone have an idea?

the code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)

    {

        switch (entered[i]) {
        case 1:
            ImageView myImageView1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.red_button);
            Animation myFadeInAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
            myImageView1.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation1); //Set animation to your ImageView
            break;

        case 2:
            ImageView myImageView2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yellow_button);
            Animation myFadeInAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
            myImageView2.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation2); //Set animation to your ImageView
            break;  
        case 3:
            ImageView myImageView3= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.green_button);
            Animation myFadeInAnimation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
            myImageView3.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation3); //Set animation to your ImageView
            break;  
        case 4:
            ImageView myImageView4= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blue_button);
            Animation myFadeInAnimation4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
            myImageView4.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation4); //Set animation to your ImageView
            break;
        default:
            //finish();
            break;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);    // one second
        }

        catch (Exception e) {} 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you run that in one of the callbacks from the system to your app like e.g. a on-click-handler.
Android accumulates all the changes you make and applies them after this callback returns.

What you can do is to write an AsyncTask that in its onPublishProgess method does the color change and then have doInBackground loop and wait and publish the progress.